# Equation of horizontal/vertical line and changing to $y=mx+c$ format

Tags: analytic-geometry

I've been given the equation $2x-3y=5$.

I was wondering whether this is a horizontal or vertical equation and how would I rearrange this to $y=mx+c$. I know that this is a fairly basic equation but the $-3y$ was throwing me off.

Comment: If you don't like the $-3y$, add $3y$ to both sides before continuing.

Comment: In answer to the first part of your question, a vertical line would have an equation $ \ ax \ = \ c \ $ and a horizontal line would have an equation $ \ by \ = \ c \ $ .  Since your equation (which is in "general form") has both an $ \ x- \ $ and a $ \ y-$ term, it is an oblique line.

Answer (score 1):

2x-3y=5

-3y=5-2x

y=(5-2x)/-3

y=(5/-3)-(2/-3)x

y=-(5/3)+(2/3)x

y=-(2/3)x-(5/3)

- it's now in y=mx+b form